# What is this Odd <Style> tag at the bottom of some websites source? Have I got malware or is this normal?

Tags: html, css

I was doing some tasks on a coding site and a task asked me to view the page source of one of its pages. Besides the standard HTML source code right at the bottom before the HTML closing tag, there was a tag like this

```
<style>a[href^="http://affiliates.pinnaclesports.com/processing/"],div[id^="taboola-stream-"],
a[href^="https://deliver.tf2www.com/"],a[href^="https://s.zlink2.com/"]
```

and so on (about 100 links) for what I can only assume to be ads.

I then checked other websites etc and the same is true for sites like Goodreads was one I found them on, is this normal for sites to run ads like this or is my browser riddled with cookies or something?

Any help is really appreciated as I am quite concerned

Comment: It's normal and no way harmful. It's just a `style` tag with bunch of selectors.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Only reason for my concern is that I sent the link to my friend and he didn't get the tag at all, same with my laptop, It's just my PC seemingly.

Comment: Do you use any adblock browser extension? The domains you list also appear here. https://github.com/Hackl0us/AdBlock-Rules-Mirror/blob/master/AdGuard-Simplified-Domain-Names-Filter.txt